# Indesign: Run the CropMarks script on all pages

Tags: adobe-indesign, crop, script

I have a document with a few hundred pages which is just an 8up layout to print a smaller document.  I was able to get the layout on all pages correct, but adding crop marks by page is going to take a while.

Is there a way to speed up this process?  Ideally I guess if I could select all the objects in the document instead of the page, but perhaps I can modify the script to handle it.

And since i'm here, is there a tutorial on apple scripting you would recommend?

Comment: on Apple Scripting, nothing comes close to the book by Matt Neuburb. He has a verbose style that's not to everyone's liking but, for me, it's the way to get to know things. Sample here: http://www.apeth.net/matt/scriptability/scriptabilityTutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean or how you are even doing crop marks page by page.  You mean you are *manually* drawing on crop marks?!

Go to File > Export and choose PDF (Print)

Click on Marks and Bleeds and set your crop marks there

They will be on every page automatically.  I recommend adding an offset equal to your bleed, but that's just my (and several other designers I know) preference.  It just looks nicer and keeps them out of the bleed, in case they need that for some reason.

[image]

If you mean you have one page with several smaller ones inside of it that need to be cut out, you could make a master page with your marks and apply that to all pages.